# Google Plus SignIn / oAuth2 - server side throwing TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, android, json, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

So I'm building simple system composed of Android application and Java EE RESTful service, and I'm having terrible problems with authorization with google. I'm implementing Google+ Sign-in and it works well on client side, which is, I am able to obtain user email, JWT idToken, and server authentication code, which I'd like to exchange for access and refresh tokens and store them in my database. This is done as follow:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .requestServerAuthCode(SERVICE_CLIENT_ID, this)
    .build();
        // ...
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

After successful connection onUploadServerAuthCode is called.

```
@Override
public boolean onUploadServerAuthCode(String idToken, String serverAuthCode) {
   //...
   //When it's called, I send serverAuthCode to my server.
}
```

Then on my server side I use the code from here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials

```
String CLIENTSECRET_LOCATION = "/WEB-INF/classes/client_secret.json";
String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");

GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow getFlow() throws IOException {
    if (flow == null) {
        InputStream in = context.getResourceAsStream(CLIENTSECRET_LOCATION);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecret = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
                JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
                JSON_FACTORY, clientSecret, SCOPES)
                .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force")
                .build();
    }
    return flow;
}

Credential exchangeCode(String authorizationCode)
        throws CodeExchangeException {
    try {
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getFlow();
        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow
                .newTokenRequest(authorizationCode)
                .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        throw new CodeExchangeException(null);
    }
}
```

**And I'm stuck there.**


If I use: **client_secret.json** from my Android App client id:

```
{
   "installed":{
       "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
       "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
       "client_email":"",
       "redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","oob"],
       "client_x509_cert_url":"",
       "client_id":"243714256753-lqcm63mXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
       "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
   }
}
```

in `exchangeCode(String)` `GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute()` throws `TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized`

And if I use: **client_secret.json** from my Service account client id:

```
{
  "private_key_id": "77bee9dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICdgIBADANBgk ... \u003d\u003d\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "243714256753-g21p1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "243714256753-g21p1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

OR

```
{
    "web": {
      "private_key_id": "77bee9dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICdgI ... \u003d\u003d\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "243714256753-g21p1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "243714256753-g21p1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "type": "service_account"
    }
}
```

in `exchangeCode()` `GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute()` throws

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "client_secret is missing."
}
```

1) What shall I do know ?
2) What's the use of JWT obtained on `onUploadServerAuthCode` ?